# C# Namespace communication

Tags: c#, methods, namespaces

may I ask (as a novice) how do I call a method of a namespace, from another? Thank you for setting up an example if possible..

For example: (1) how do I set the properties of the MY_PRIMARY class to use them and (2) how do I call the AddNumbers method while in the MY_SECONDARY namespace? Thank you..

```
    using.. etc

    namespace MY_PRIMARY
    {
        public partial class SomethingHere
        {
            public Boolean holiday { get; set; } = false;
            public int age { get; set; } = 18;
            //etc... 
        }

        class Program
        {
            private static void Main()
            {
            // some code here.. and..

            public int AddNumbers(int number1, int number2)
            {
                int result = number1 + number2;
                return result;
            }
        }
    };

    namespace MY_SECONDARY
    {
        public partial class SomethingElseHere
        {
            public Boolean holiday { get; set; } = false;
            public int age { get; set; } = 18;
            //etc... 
        }

        class Program
        {
            static void Main()
            {
            // some code here..
            }
            // and..

            Program outer = new Program();
            outer.AddNumbers(3, 18);       // <--- this is failing..
        }
    }

;
```

Comment: `Program outer = new Program();` is `MY_SECONDARY.Program`, not `MY_PRIMARY.Program`.

Comment: The problem is that you have two `Program` classes and only one has the `AddNumbers` method.  You'd want `var outer = new MY_PRIMARY.Program();` in order to have the one that has the method.  But then anything you add to `MY_SECONDARY.Program` would not be in that object.

Comment: Are these in the same file? If so, I would think this will cause problems in running your console application. If they are in separate console projects, then that would be a problem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces are meant to group objects semantically. I'm kind of confused why you have 2 program classes. It would make more sense to have one class library, and one program. Anyway...
Suppose you have an Object1 in namespace Program.First,
And an Object2 in Program.Second
Object2 has a method named someMethod.
What you would do to call this method is 
a) either add "using Program.Second", on you first class.
b) make an instance of Program.Second.Object2, and call the method on that.

https://www.programiz.com/csharp-programming/namespaces

So suppose you want to make an object of Program() do this:

```
using System;

namespace MY_PRIMARY
{
    public partial class SomethingHere
    {
        public Boolean holiday { get; set; } = false;
        public int age { get; set; } = 18;
        //etc... 
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public int AddNumbers(int number1, int number2)
        {
            int result = number1 + number2;
            return result;
        }
    }
} 

namespace MY_SECONDARY
{
    public partial class SomethingElseHere
    {
        public Boolean holiday { get; set; } = false;
        public int age { get; set; } = 18;
        //etc... 
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {    
            MY_PRIMARY.Program outer = new MY_PRIMARY.Program();
            outer.AddNumbers(3, 18);   
        }
    }
}
```

(EDIT) updated my answer, i copied your code and saw that your namespaces were not closed off, therefor, you had nested namespaces, and classes in there. plus, some of the code was directly in your class instead of in a function.

Also, don't define 2 Main() methods, that's the entrypoint of the application.

Comment: Thank you so much. As a matter of fact, I have tried, to be honest, but I tried again as per your recommendation. I must be doing something wrong (the two namespaces are in the same file, to answer a comment). the error I get: "The name 'outer.AddNumbers' does not exist in the current context" and I can't figure out why...

Comment: make the program class public

Comment: @Nick Post actual minimal code that reproduces your issue, then. The change Glenn made should be sufficient to fix the sample code you posted so far.

Comment: This is what I have:


namespace MY_PRIMARY
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        { }

        public int AddNumbers(int number1, int number2)
        {
            int result = number1 + number2;
            return result;
        }
    }
};


namespace MY_SECONDARY
{

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        { }

        MY_PRIMARY.Program outer = new MY_PRIMARY.Program();

        outer.AddNumbers(3, 18);

    }
};

Comment: What error is that exactly? is your code in seperate files or all in one file? You should also really use different names for different classes.

Comment: also, remove the ; after the namespaces

Comment: This is what I have (in one file), the simplest form (without "using"s...)
`namespace MY_PRIMARY
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        { }

        public int AddNumbers(int number1, int number2)
        {
            int result = number1 + number2;
            return result;
        }
    }
};


namespace MY_SECONDARY
{

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        { }

        MY_PRIMARY.Program outer = new MY_PRIMARY.Program();

        outer.AddNumbers(3, 18);

    }
};`

Comment: this is what i mean by remove the ; :namespace MY_PRIMARY { public class Program { private static void Main() { } public int AddNumbers(int number1, int number2) { int result = number1 + number2; return result; } } } namespace MY_SECONDARY { public class Program { static void Main() { } MY_PRIMARY.Program outer = new MY_PRIMARY.Program(); outer.AddNumbers(3, 18); } }
now what's the exact error you are getting?

Comment: The error I get is only on the line where outer.AddNumbers(3, 18); is and mentions: "The name 'outer.AddNumbers' does not exist in the current context" - Thank you Glenn, I deleted the semicolon at the end of each namespace, that was ok (no errors) but still I got the same error on outer.AddNumbers...

Comment: As far as i can see, your code will not compile as long as those ';' are after the namespaces }. remove those, and i think the error will go away

Comment: @Glenn van Acker Thank you!!! It worked, I will take a moment to call myself various names :-) and next time I will be careful to close namespaces (and read some more). Thank you for your kind help and the your time, greatly appreciated!

Comment: No problem, i remember calling myself various names over similar problems :P

Comment: @Nick why was this answer unaccepted, if it solved your problem?

Comment: Hi, I think I accepted as solution the previous one because it ran first. I will try to accept both!
@FabioIn: it worked yes. Kindly see that the one namespace is inside the other, I would go with the second one which actually covers two independent namespaces. I apologize for the delay responding..

Answer (score 1):

...A little modification in POSITIONS of functions and classes... please, see:

```
using Alias = MY_PRIMARY.Program;

namespace MY_PRIMARY
{
    public partial class SomethingHere
    {
        public Boolean holiday { get; set; } = false;
        public int age { get; set; } = 18;
        //etc... 
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            // some code here.. and..
        }

        public int AddNumbers(int number1, int number2)
        {
            int result = number1 + number2;
            return result;
        }
    };

    namespace MY_SECONDARY
    {
        public partial class SomethingElseHere
        {
            public Boolean holiday { get; set; } = false;
            public int age { get; set; } = 18;
            //etc... 
        }

        class Program
        {
            static void Main()
            {
                // some code here..
                // and..
                Alias outer = new Alias();
                outer.AddNumbers(3, 18);       // <--- OKAY...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See more:
[Using namespaces (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/using-namespaces)

Comment: @Fabioln : thank you sir it worked! Now, I do understand the syntax here, but, shouldn't be allowed to use the MY_PRIMARY.Program *without* putting a using Alias ?

Comment: @Nick, I think only change "Alias" per "MY_PRIMARY.Program" ... Or change the name "Alias" for other name... Example: "My_Program" ...